# @Override gives error in eclipse?

Tags: java, android

When I import project from workspace in eclipse, it gives error at `@Override` annotation. If the project has any method that has an annotation it displays as an error and when I remove it works fine, but when I have a major project that has a lot of annotations, what should I do fix it?

Comment: Please share some code, so that we can see why it is showing error. May be it does not show errors in you "major project"

Comment: Are you sure that the methods you are trying to override are not private methods? and also that they take the exact same argument?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're using Java 1.5 which does not support @Override annotations for implementation overrides. Go into the Eclipse settings and set the language level to 1.6.

EDIT - to change the language level go To Project > Properties > Java Compiler and set the language level there. You may need to click to enable project specific settings.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have set your project language level to something below 1.5, where @Override was introduced. Or, you have it set below 6, and the project code uses @Override for methods implementing interface methods, which was only introduced in Java 6. Change your project language level.

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` is not android specific but a java annotation. If you get errors you might have Java 1.5 selected in you eclipse/project settings. Change that to Java 1.6 or above and it should disappear.