# How to configure Eclipse to use Phonegap on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, cordova

> **Definition**
>
> *Phonegap = tool to make things such as HTML5/Javascript games into
>   phones. It is pretty cool because desktop versions should work in
>   phones without extensive redoing things for other platforms.*

I can find the general instructions but everything about Eclipse and things like that. I cannot find a word about Ubuntu such as [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) unless a lot of google -spam with a massive amount of confusing threads about different platforms where people are more-or-less bullying one another like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658366) with red-herrings such as `google`. I wish there was some nice make -files to do things but no, the README is instruction to read the more-or-less ambiguous Get-Started. So:

**Problems**

1. Where can I find step-by-step instructions on Ubuntu to set up Phonegap?
2. I hope some outlining over different platforms.
3. ADT Plugin is not getting installed in Eclipse. Why?

> **Android Eclipse ADT -problem**
>
> I can find [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing) the instructions
>   but cannot move forward for some odd reason, no instructions or help
>   -text to proceed. You can see in the photo that it does not allow me to click OK although I am following the instructions. I wish I could do this on console!
>
> [image]

Comment: @MorrisonChang: thank you for the notice, I am no pro to set up things on Eclipse particularly with this kind of oddities like above where I am trying to install the ADT plugin for Eclipse but well it end up to non-clickable buttons without instructions. I wish there was some easy way of getting all installed like one make -file or apt-get...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Definitions**
>
> *AVP = Android virtual phone (you do not need all phones to test your code, use emulator)*
>
> *ADB = application to push application from command-line to the phone*
>
> *ADT -plugin in Eclipse = adding some buttons to Eclipse for things such as to add AVPs*
>
> *ADT = Android Development Tools (not sure what they are actually, perhaps emulation-related things containing things such as linux
>   kernels, APIs etc)*

I am trying to provide instructions for console -power-users, hopefully helping to get things fast set-up instead of wasting time a lot with the cumbersome instructions.

> **1. set up the development environment such as the Android SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).**
>
> ```
> $ wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r18-linux.tgz
>
> $ tar -xvzf *.tgz
>
> $ ...follow README or some tutorial there...
> ```
>
> I. Now go back to the Android SDK site where you can find the ADT Plugin for Eclipse
>   [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). The
>   unclikable button becomes clickable if you search now with the
>   search-bar for Android something. The ADT stands for Android
>   Development Tools so install everything you get there under something
>   tools or related.
>
> II. Fix the @override -problem (shortly requires 1.6 compiler -compliance-level), more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521131/override-gives-error-in-eclipse).
>
> III. Test your Android installation work by loading an Android Sample -file and then plugging in your phone (with USB -debugging enabled: Settings > Development > click) or use Android Virtual Phone (=AVP)
>
> > ```
> > $ adb devices   # Shows your physics devices such 
> >                 # as phones with USB -debugging enabled.
> >
> > $ adb install ~/workspace/yourChosenSampleDemo/bin/*.apk 
> >                 # Your first Android -app emerges to your phone, have FuN!
> > ```
>
> **2. Set up the Phonegap with the below:**
>
> > 1. Some general instructions apparently [here](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/2010/01/building-phonegap-on-ubuntu/).
> > 2. iOS: you need Xcode so somewhat limited.
> > 3. Perhaps useful, source -code
> >        [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap) and general download
> >        [here](http://phonegap.com/download).

The instructions are extremely inaccesible with Eclipse's click-click-something, poor! After wasting time with Eclipse's symlinks, I swiched to the console:

```
$ tree|less
$ search for the files needed, mark them done or use find -command directly ^C
$ copy the files to some dir such as ~/Android/Public so easier to do ^C
$ things at once ^C
$ pwd
/home/xyz/workspace/HelloCordova/res
$ cp ~/Android/phonegap-phonegap-475bfd2/lib/android/xml/* .
$ cp ~/Android/Public/cordova-1.7.0.js assets/www/
$ cp ~/Android/Public/cordova-1.7.0.jar libs/
```

Comment: ...if I can correctly remember, this tutorial does not contain the instructions to use the Phonegab so my answer misses the last part of using Phonegab but now no time to add it -- perhaps someone else reading this through and setting things up could add them there, thank you.