# Autoboxing can't convert an int to an Integer

Tags: java

I am a complete beginner and I'm trying to learn java. I read about the concept of `Autoboxing` and `Unboxing` [here](http://www.studytonight.com/java/autoboxing-unboxing-java.php).

I am working on java version 1.8.0_05 and using Eclipse.

The code is :

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer iob = 100; // shows error -> Type mismatch: Cannot convert from int to Integer
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/dGBgIX). Not really sure what's going on for you. Code looks perfectly OK to me. First guess would be some kind of setting mismatch going on...

Comment: The eclipse is showing error to me. Also after forcing the compilation it throws me an exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer

 at com.start.variables.Boxing.main(Boxing.java:6)`

Comment: Is your Integer java.lang.Integer?

Comment: Yes I didn't include any other package yet. Its plain program with java.lang loaded only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to have your language level set to at least 1.5/5.0 to take advantage of autoboxing/unboxing.

Change your settings in `Project --> Properties --> Java Compiler`, chances are, it's not set to the right level.

Note this is NOT directly tied to the version of the JDK you're using, it simply means the level in which your java code will be interpreted as if it were no higher than the language level version, using any particular version of the JDK that is at least at or higher than the given language level setting.

IE: you're using JDK 1.8+, setting your language level to 5.0 means you will only be able to use java features that are up to JDK 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the wrong language level set in Eclipse.

See [@Override gives error in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521131/override-gives-error-in-eclipse) :

> to change the language level go To Project > Properties > Java Compiler and set the language level there. You may need to click to enable project specific settings.

Comment: I see that my project is running on CDC which has included the java version I've mentioned above.

Comment: In Project > Properties > Java Build Path, all the libraries included are of 1.8.0_05

Comment: The library isn't the problem. Javac has source/target compatibility parameters, so even if you're using the version 1.8 JDK, Eclipse or your build tool can still be configured to interpret the source as any earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing feature is available since Java 1.5.

Make sure that you are running at least Java 1.5.

Otherwise you need new Integer(100) or Integer.valueOf(100). Or just declare it as int instead of Integer.

What you can do is to check the **PATH** and **JAVA_HOME** using:

```
Object obj = System.getenv();
System.out.println(obj);
```

You should get an output like:

> {JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_5612=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner,
>   SHELL=/bin/bash,
>   TMPDIR=/var/folders/zw/n554nzl151sgtr5rqftblcjm0000gn/T/,
>   com.apple.java.jvmMode=client, __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0,
>   APP_ICON_5439=../Resources/sts.icns,
>   **PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/fede/jdk1.8/bin**, **JAVA_HOME=/Users/fede/jdk1.8/**, USER=fede,
>   com.apple.java.jvmTask=CommandLine_Manual.java, HOME=/Users/fede,
>   LOGNAME=fede, Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-5UzUjs/Render,
>   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-2okgJL/Listeners, __CHECKFIX1436934=1,
>   JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD_5439=1}

That can help figuring out what is happening