# Storing value in integer array

Tags: java, arrays

Its simple but I am getting confused with below code, I am able to store and retrieve value from Character and string array but not from Integer.

```
Integer[] intArray = {1,2,3,4,5}; //Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer
String[] str1 = {"pk1", "pk2", "pk3", "pk4", "pk5"}; //works fine
Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' }; //Works fine
```

Comment: All three lines compile fine for me. Are you really using java? Which compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591491/autoboxing-cant-convert-an-int-to-an-integer

Comment: Yes i`m using java compiler only.

Comment: You mention generics in a comment. Have you taken some failing generics and written this example based on that? Or you just working with ancient java compliance level as mentioned in the duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

The type `int` in a primitive type in java where it's parent class (known as primitive wrapper class) is `Integer`. Whilst the two essentially represent identical data, they are not directly translatable directly from assignment. E.g.

```
int foo = 56;
Integer bar = foo;
```

will throw compilation error (**if and only if** your source compilation level has been set to <= 1.4, but getting on to this later).

The correct way to convert between them would be:

```
int foo = 56;
Integer bar = new Integer(foo);
```

though this seems unnecessarily complex/verbose. So, the good people at Oracle/Sun Microsystems since JDK 1.5/5.0 (released 11 years ago!) introduced the concept of [autoboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing) and unboxing. Where the former code will automatically be interpreted as the latter code at compiler level resolving any issues with equating primitive wrapper types with primitive types.

This concept is also applied onto arrays initialized with {} **but** not onto existing arrays, e.g:

```
int[] foo = new int[50];
Integer[] bar = foo;
```

will always give a compiler error regardless of the version you are compiling for. Since autoboxing would only work on `primitive -> primitive wrapper type` and not `primitive[] -> primitive wrapper type[]`.

In your case, it seems that your source compliance level (normally set by `-source xx`) has been set to 1.4 or less (or you are using a compiler from 2002, who knows). To resolve, raise the source compliance equal to or above 1.5 to enable autoboxing being used.

Note: upon the disabling of autoboxing (via 1.4 or lower source value) your character example should fail too (given `Character` is the primitive wrapper type for `char`, the primitive type you are initializing from). My guess is you are using a non-standard, non-conforming compiler that supports only subset of language features **or** that you somehow attempted to compile different parts of your program under different source values.

Comment: Nice explanation Thanks.!! my compliance level is set to 1.6 and using same version  JRE. Don`t know what is the problem, could you please suggest me how to set that, so that my eclipse support conversion type programming easily. Basically not able to work any of collections programs(getting exceptions always).

Comment: Trying to add the value in ArrayList getting error message. "The method add(int, Integer) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int)".

Comment: @user4143078 Perhaps try to reinstall Eclipse/JDK and install the latest version of JDK (as of the time of writing, 8u45). Seems like a glitch/bug in your compiler or Eclipse. I also suggest clean/rebuilding your workspace to get rid of any old/invalid class files it may have already generated.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` and `int` are two different data types in Java. `Integer` is a wrapper class providing Integer objects and static methods, and `int` is a primitive data-type.

Your code will compile, but if think in your case it would be better to use this:

```
int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: I agree both are different data types in JAVA, what if i wanted to store the value in integer type only..? I was trying generics where the generic type can print all the different type object values, were able to get results for string and character but getting error at integer conversion.

Comment: For the String, it's about the default assignment. "pk1" is by default autoboxed into a "String" object. However, I am confused how 'H' can get autoboxed into a Character object and 1 not get autoboxed into an Integer.

Comment: @damith219 *""pk1" is by default autoboxed into a "String" object"* What? *"pk1"* is a String literal, there is no need to autobox something there.