# Unable to assign primitives to Object array in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, autoboxing

I am initiating object array as below:

```
Object a[] = new Object[4];

a[0] = 1; //while assigning integer value, am getting an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert Integer to Object
a[1] = 'A'; //while assigning char value, am getting an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert char to Object
a[2] = 12.33//while assigning integer value, am getting an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert double to Object
a[3] = "Hello"; //Accepting only string values.
```

PLease suggest where went wrong? is it configuration issue? I am using:

```
Java Version jdk1.8.0_151,
jre1.8.0_151,

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600
```

Comment: @MCEmperor isn't automatically boxed?

Comment: Those are primitive types, that's why.

Comment: @StephanHogenboom My bad, they are autoboxed indeed.

Comment: @MCEmperor,  but i am able to store the same data types in another system(my Collegue system)

Comment: @Praveen Autoboxing indeed works on other systems. That means that either your compiler doesn't follow the specs, or you're using an old compiler.

Comment: @MCEmperor, how to update the compiler or to get the issue resolved?

Comment: @Praveen It depens. Are you using an IDE? If yes, which?

Comment: He is using Eclipse (according to old title), which version? (You can update to the most recent Eclipse)

Comment: @MCEmperor, am not using IDE. i am using Europa.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE. And its using its own compiler, not the default Java compiler. Thats why people ask you which Eclipse version you are using.

Comment: @Praveen Eclipse *is* an [IDE](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). You need to update Eclipse. If you already have the newest Eclipse version, then you should [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int`, `float`, `double`, and `char` are all `primitive` types so they cannot be "converted" as `Object`.

`String`s are `Object`s, therefore, the can be added in the array.

To achieve what you probably want, you can convert them to their equivalent Object:

```
Object a[] = new Object[4];
a[0] = Integer.valueOf(1); 
a[1] = Character.valueOf('A');
a[2] = Float.valueOf(12.33);
a[3] = "Hello";
```

Comment: **Never** use the `Integer` constructor. Always use `Integer.of()`.

Comment: @MCEmperor why are you saying that?

Comment: If this is the case, why don't I get OPs issue in my eclipse?

Comment: @niccord Because it's good practise and you may not be aware of it. Since newer Java versions, it's also Deprecated, just like Zabuza says. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html).

Comment: @niccord Because its own documentation says so. Its deprecated for good reasons.

Comment: it's deprecated from version 9, I didn't know that. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Did you test the code? It seems (see question comments) that this is covered by autoboxing and might be a bug with Eclipses compiler.

Comment: @Zabuza it works, actually. I have taken for granted it didn't.

Comment: @niccord By the way, the reason (using) the constructor is deprecated is that it is bypassing the caching mechanism for a certain range of values (`-128` to `127`, as [guaranteed by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)). With using `Integer.valueOf()` you leverage the caching mechanism, gaining performance. [See here its implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l1052).

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the error message you would be getting if you are using a compiler compliance level lower than 5. Note that this is different from the Java version on your system. See the fix here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591529/11595728 .

Answer (score 1):

I have not encountered the problem you described. I think it is automatically boxed, At least in my configuration environment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object a[] = new Object[4];

        a[0] = 1; //while assigning integer value, am getting an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert Integer to Object
        a[1] = 'A'; //while assigning char value, am getting an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert char to Object
        a[2] = 12.33;//while assigning integer value, am getting an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert double to Object
        a[3] = "Hello"; //Accepting only string values.
        for(Object i:a) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
    }
```

right click -> Run As -> Java Application,
the console output:

```
1
A
12.33
Hello
```

Comment: My Java Version jdk1.8.0_151, jre1.8.0_151, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600

Comment: This does not really explain or solve the issue, nor add anything new. The content of your answer is just "can not reproduce" which should probably rather be a comment instead of an answer, see [answer].