# type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to do a two dimension array.

this is the code:
public class TwoDimensionalArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Integer str[][]=new Integer[3][3];

    
    str [0][0]=10; the error is here 'cannot convert from int to integer'
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire exception stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autoboxing can't convert an int to an Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591491/autoboxing-cant-convert-an-int-to-an-integer)

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks so much. My question has been answered. You guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

Integer and int are different data types. If you don't specify, it's assumed by the language to be int. I would solve it as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer str[][]=new Integer[3][3];
    Integer myInt = 10;
    str [0][0]=myInt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you raw. I was trying to do a two dimensional array, with the following: str [0][0]=10; str[0][1]=20; str[0][2]=30; str[1][0]=40; str[1][1]=50; and so on to give me a 3x3 matrix where i can print out the value for column and rows which should be 3 respectively.

Comment: Sure thing kelz. You could also cast 10 as Integer, but that tends to be language dependent. I was aiming for something that was language agnostic.